# Software similar to message queue that can re-order events

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm looking for some software that acts a bit like a message queue, but can re-order events. Something like logstash, kafka or rabbit MQ.

My use case is that we're getting events in, mostly in order, but occasionally one will come in with an older timestamp, and it'd be nice for this to "jump the queue" and be processed next. (We can handle out-of-order events, but it's less efficient).

Queued items need to have disk-backed guaranteed delivery (i.e. the program restarting shouldn't result in data loss)

The closest I've been able to find is [Rabbit MQ's priority queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html) - that allows you to define up to 256 priority levels<sup>1</sup>, and higher priority messages are delivered before lower priority ones. This can probably be made to work with some kind of heuristic (e.g. the priority level is `current_time - message_time` in minutes), but it doesn't seem ideal.

Is there anything better?

<sup>1</sup> Although it's recommended not to use more than 10

Answer (score 1):

You will have the most flexibility with Kafka.

if you use KSQL on top then you can add priority, processed attributes to your message then you can create streams, sort, filter streams efficiently based on your needs.